# Seagate external hard disk does not power down

Tags: memory, external-hard-drive, shutdown, power

When my computer is off, this external hard disk remains on, consuming power. It is permanently warm, and inside components are active (perhaps the fan?).

I have a UPS for the system so a complete power off is not convenient. At the moment, I physically disconnect the drive from the system after power off.

Is there a setting in the BIOS that might control this power loss?

Comment: Is this an external expansion *disk*? Is it attached via USB or eSATA?

Comment: External expansion desk top memory attached via USB3

Comment: It is unusual to have external memory, whereas external disks are common.  Perhaps you are using a non-standard term?  If you add the model number to the question, it will help identify the source of the issue.

Comment: Seagate. 2TB EXPANSION DESKTOP USB3 STBV2000100

Comment: Seagate 2TB EXPANSION DESKTOP USB3 STBV2000100. The computer is unable to safely disconnect the drive... It appears to be always be in use. When the computer is turned off, the disk drive seems to be perrmanently powered up- warm, with the internal fan operating(?) and needlessly wasting power and wearing itself out. I have resorted to disconnecting the USB cable after Turning the computer off. A total nuisance...and a reminder why I should never have purchased it. I have two other WEstern Digital drives with none of these issues....